# ListView/ScrollablePositionedList.builder animation item in Flutter - How to animate

Tags: flutter, listview, transition

I tried to make this animation (https://www.instagram.com/p/CQ3XpZaD-yM/) but I couldn't.

First I tried to find the item in the screen with Listview.builder and ScrollController and next googling I found this dependence (https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list), however I couldn't make the same effect and code became dirty.

For scale the items, I used a Transform.scale.
So I don't have a smooth transition between items cause I have a boolean decision... and other strange issue when you are scrolling  quickly, the behavior is not the expected and doesn't make the scaling, worked ok when you scroll "slow".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
  final ItemPositionsListener itemPositionsListener =
      ItemPositionsListener.create();
  double scaleOne = 1.0;
  double scaleTwo = 1.0;
  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.35,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
                  itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: itemPositionsListener.itemPositions,
                        builder: (context, value, Widget? child) {
                          if (itemPositionsListener
                              .itemPositions.value.isNotEmpty) {
                            var scroll = itemPositionsListener
                                .itemPositions.value
                                .toList();

                            print(scroll);
                            index = scroll[0].index;
                            scaleOne =
                                (scroll[0].itemTrailingEdge * 1.5).clamp(0, 1);
                          }
                          return _ContainerAndText(
                              size: size,
                              ///How I can make a smooth move?
                              scale: index == i ? scaleOne : 1.0,
                              i: i);
                        });
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ContainerAndText extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ContainerAndText({
    Key? key,
    required this.size,
    required this.scale,
    required this.i,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Size size;
  final double scale;
  final int i;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        width: size.width * 0.61,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: size.width * 0.5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.primaries[i],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: size.width * 0.3, bottom: 15),
              height: size.height * 0.30,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Transform(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                transform: Matrix4.identity()..scale(scale, scale),
                child: Text(
                  '${i}',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 260),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With PageView.builder could help...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
  final ItemPositionsListener itemPositionsListener =
      ItemPositionsListener.create();
  final _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.83);
  double currentPage = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController.addListener(_listenerPage);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.removeListener(_listenerPage);
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void _listenerPage() {
    setState(() {
      currentPage = _pageController.page!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.35,
              width: size.width,
              child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: _pageController,
                  itemCount: 10,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    final result = currentPage - i;
                    double value = (-1 * result * result + 1);
                    return _ContainerAndText(
                        i: i,
                        size: size,
                        scale: result == i ? 1 - value : 0.8 * value);
                  })),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ContainerAndText extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ContainerAndText({
    Key? key,
    required this.size,
    required this.scale,
    required this.i,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Size size;
  final double scale;
  final int i;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        //color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
        width: size.width * 0.61,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: size.width * 0.5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.primaries[i],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: size.width * 0.3, bottom: 15),
              height: size.height * 0.30,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Transform(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                transform: Matrix4.identity()..scale(scale, scale),
                child: Text(
                  '${i}',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 260),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use Hero widget with same key in order to achieve similar transition.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/hero-animations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).